# What is this symbol?

Tags: symbols

I'm currently unable to post images, sorry. It's a box with what appears to be an x in it, only the centre of the x is a box, and the bottom two legs of the x are smaller and vertical. I've tried reverse-image searching, but nothing's come up.

It looks a little like this:

___________ 
|  _            _   |
|    \         /     |
|      \___/       |
|      |___|        |
|      |      |       |
|__________  |

But more like just a box with an x in it from further away.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Where do you see this mysterious symbol?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Drawing the symbol with ascii characters might help people understand.

Comment: I've seen this symbol as part of a web address and also as an output from Xcode when I've asked it to print something out after a user input (possibly a tab key...?).